# Postgres Deadlock on CircleCI

Tags: postgresql, circleci

Recently, I've upped my single build concurrency on CircleCI to 11 instances.  Intermittently, I get

> PG::TRDeadlockDetected

errors in some of the build instances.  I don't know enough about the CircleCI architecture to be able to troubleshoot this.  Does anyone have insight on this?

```
PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 11634 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 19091 of database 18000; blocked by process 11840.
Process 11840 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 18632 of database 18000; blocked by process 11634.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
: TRUNCATE TABLE "addresses", "users", "hits" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE; (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:148:in `truncate_tables'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:202:in `block in clean'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb:17:in `disable_referential_integrity'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:198:in `clean'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:86:in `clean'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:79:in `block in clean'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:79:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/database_cleaner-1.2.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:79:in `clean'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-rails-1.4.0/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/database_cleaner.rb:9:in `After'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_hook.rb:14:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:114:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:108:in `block in execute_after'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:107:in `reverse_each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:107:in `execute_after'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:19:in `after'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:112:in `block in fire_hook'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:111:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:111:in `fire_hook'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:112:in `after'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:99:in `before_and_after'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:81:in `block in with_hooks'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `block (3 levels) in around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:in `block in around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:94:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:94:in `block (3 levels) in execute_around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/features/support/env.rb:84:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/icn/features/support/env.rb:84:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_hook.rb:14:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:114:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in execute_around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:97:in `execute_around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in `around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:123:in `around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:93:in `around'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:80:in `with_hooks'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:32:in `block in accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:79:in `with_visitor'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:31:in `accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:58:in `block in visit_feature_element'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:57:in `visit_feature_element'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:38:in `block in accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in `accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:27:in `block in visit_feature'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:26:in `visit_feature'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `block in accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:27:in `accept'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:21:in `block in visit_features'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_features'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:48:in `run!'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.8/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/icn/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

When running a build in parallel, CircleCI uses isolated containers, each with their own database instance, so the problem won't be from the parallel executions interacting with each other.

It is possible, however, that the splitting of your tests across the machines is exposing unexpected behavior or issues with unclean setup or teardown between tests.

It's obviously harder when it's intermittent, but you can rerun the build with ssh enabled and then connect to the container when you get an error and inspect all the logs. That should give you a better idea of where the deadlock is occurring.

Also, CircleCI has direct support in app or at sayhi@circleci.com if you need help debugging.